# Google API is very slow while downloading multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, performance, download, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm struggling with a thorny issue.
My file downloads via Google Api C# are **very** slow for an totally unknown reason.

The files I get are well the good ones, no corrupted files, no duplicates files The content is fine.
For the test, I have 15 files with size between 1MB and 3MB for a total size of 28MB on a Shared Team Drive.

My home download speed is 3MB/s (it should be then about 9 / 10 seconds for 28MB, this is the time I get when downloading via Google Drive application directly). But it takes **117** seconds to finish.

I am using the "Google.Apis.Drive.v3" package:
[image]

I tried to make my code as simpliest as possible to isolate the issue :

```
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            foreach (GD.File file in files)
                await service.Files.Get(file.Id).DownloadAsync(new MemoryStream());
            sw.Stop();
```

"files" contains the 15 files I described above, I do a simple foreach on it and I use DownloadAsync function.
Here i am doing nothing with the stream but this is for test purposes. I tried with synchronous, asynchronous.

I tried also with a very high speed connection like 100MB/s connection and it takes 114 seconds to finish.

I tried with MediaDownloader class directly, but I couldn't make it work at all (it downloads empty files...).

Do you have any idea why do I have this type of issue ?
And do you have any suggestion how I can debug this ?

**[EDIT]**
I tried also with a single file which has 63MB size. And I tracked the downloaded bytes into a JSON. I capture bytes downloaded at a certain time...

```cs
                Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                JsonArray eventsJSON = new();
                JsonObject fileJSON = new() {
                        { "id", fileId },
                        { "events", eventsJSON }
                    };

                FilesResource.GetRequest getRequest = service.Files.Get(fileId);
                getRequest.MediaDownloader.ChunkSize = 262144;
                getRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += progress =>
                {
                    JsonObject eventJSON = new()
                        {
                            { "time", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0 },
                            { "bytes", progress.BytesDownloaded  },
                            { "finished", progress.Status == DownloadStatus.Completed }
                        };
                    eventsJSON.Add(eventJSON);
                };
                await getRequest.DownloadAsync(new MemoryStream());

                sw.Stop();

                fileJSON.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, JsonNode?>("finalTime", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0));
                await hRes.WriteAsJsonAsync(fileJSON);
```

**The result is surprising : the first bytes received began 30 seconds after I call the download function** and finished at 57 seconds, 57 - 30 = 27 seconds is a normal speed for this file size !
What's happenning !? Why I need 30 seconds to begin the download !? Do you have any idea ?

**[EDIT 2]**
I used Wireshark to check what's happening exactly between Google Drive API and my program. The result is exactly the same, it takes 30 seconds when I request a download, look at the time values :
[image]

Wireshark is confirming that nothing happens in these 30 seconds. I am going to lose hope...

**[EDIT 3]**
I tried to directly send the request via Postman instead of using C# client API, I have the exact same issue.
I tried also with the built-in Google developpers UI where I can send the request, and it takes 38 seconds (about 20 seconds better !), WHY !? In all cases, 38 seconds still slow... It should be 25 seconds max...

I forgot to mention that is only the get files content which is slow, if I ask anything else, like listing files in a folder, it's like instant.

**[EDIT 4]**
I understand now that Google Drive API is checking viruses on files, every files... Including files within a zip archive. This is a big issue for me as I am suggesting only Excel and Powerpoint files to my users (I remind you MS Office files are archives).

So the strange thing is :

- that Google Drive "classic" (I mean using normal Google Drive) seems to be ignoring the virus scan when this is an archive and the download begins quickly.
- that Google Drive API keeps checking viruses at any cost...

So, YES, if I am not wrong, Google Drive API is well the issue !
Is someone aware of any workaround ?